# Ordinary Differential Equations - Poincaré Bendixson

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve next problem: Let $X$ be a $C^1$ vector field in $\mathbb{R^2}$ end $\gamma$ an orbit of the $X$. Prove  that if  $\gamma$  is not a periodic orbit or a singularity then $\omega(\gamma)\cap\alpha(\gamma)=\emptyset$ or  $\omega(\gamma)\cap\alpha(\gamma)$ is a singular point.

Comment: I think do you mean that $\gamma$ is not a closed orbit?

Comment: I meant periodic orbit. Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The two dimentional linear systems have their orbits described in function of the proper values, in effect they are the focus, the center, the node, etc.

In all this phase diagrams, the orbits have the $\omega$-limit and the $\alpha$-limit equal to the $0$ and the $\infty$ (or vice-versa), except in the case of the singular point $0$, or the center, where the orbits are periodic and then not only the intersection is not empty but the are actually the same $\omega$-limit $= \alpha$-limit.

So, in the $C^1$ vector field $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if and orbit $\gamma$ is not periodic or a singularity, then $\omega(\gamma)\cap\alpha(\gamma)= \emptyset$